React.createContext does not work on initial page load
I've inherited a project that is using React 16 much to my dismay :D and am finding that I'm unable to access my context on the apps initial load. Once making saves to the codebase and the app hot-reloading then it works as expected.
App.js
export const RequestManagerContext = createContext(null);

const App = () => {
  const [requestManager, setRequestManager] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    setRequestManager(new RequestManager())
  }, []);
  return (<div className="App">
      {
        !requestManager ? 'loading' : <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
        <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme, changeTheme }}>
          <RequestManagerContext.Provider value={requestManager}>
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
              <CssBaseline />
              <link
                rel="stylesheet"
                href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
              />
              <ErrorBoundary>
                <Router />
                {renderLocalStorageBanner()}
              </ErrorBoundary>
            </ThemeProvider>
          </RequestManagerContext.Provider>
        </ThemeContext.Provider>
      </LocalizationProvider>
      }
    </div>
  );
};

Trying to digest the context
import { RequestManagerContext } from './App'

class PrivateRoute extends React.Component {
  static contextType = RequestManagerContext;
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      isAuthenticated: false,
      isAdmin: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    console.log(this.context); // {}
  };

  return (<div className="App">
      {
        !requestManager ? 'loading' : <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
        <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme, changeTheme }}>
          <RequestManagerContext.Provider value={requestManager}>
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
              <CssBaseline />
              <link
                rel="stylesheet"
                href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
              />
              <ErrorBoundary>
                <Router />
                {renderLocalStorageBanner()}
              </ErrorBoundary>
            </ThemeProvider>
          </RequestManagerContext.Provider>
        </ThemeContext.Provider>
      </LocalizationProvider>
      }
    </div>
  );
};

The issue is, this.context when initially loading the app returns an object.
I will also say, the logic gate of: requestManager ? 'loading'  and storing this in useState was just incase I could stop the components from rendering until we have a value for the requestManager
As seen here below, the RequestManager is available inside the App.js, but not in the context.


First thing to suggest would be to use !Object.keys(requestManager).length instead of !requestManager

Second, please check if new RequestManager() returns empty object at any point in time

So its a weird one, if I do: setRequestManager({ hutber: true }) in the App.js's useEffect it will still return the {} until I make changes to a file. Its a weird one for sure

This looks like the problem is a circular dependency between App.js and the component file, as the error message suggests.
i.e. App.js imports the component. The component imports RequestManagerContext from App.js.
Try moving the context declaration to a separate file that both App.js and the component file import.

Amazingly I was just coming to write the same thing :D So thank you!
